# is it possible to edit a field in a VCL TDBGrid with TADOTable as a data source?

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-2007, vcl, tdbgrid

I recently modified some old UI code using Delphi's VCL to use ADO instead of BDE.  One of the screens used a TDBGrid control to modify the underlying DataSource, but it appears that is no longer possible to edit the values in the grid.  Here is how I have it configured:

TDBGrid->TDataSource->TADOTable

I found this post on another forum that seemed related:
http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/alt.comp.lang.borland-delphi/2009-08/msg00023.html

Is this a limitation of ADO?  Or do I simply need to change the settings of a control somewhere? (cursor type or something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem.  When I converted the project from Delphi 6 to Delphi 2007, it changed the Options property of the TDBGrid control to seemingly random values (perhaps some defaults?).  In this case, the dgEditing option was set to false.